# Regex - Match range 55.000 - 300.00

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex expression matching all numbers between 55 up to 300 including decimals (e.g. 55.1234 or 66.324).

https://regex101.com/r/aPlUs0/3

I know how to obtain the results for 50 up to 300, but do not know how to adapt the code.

```
^(?:[6-9]\d|[1-2]\d{2,2})(?:\.\d+)?$|^300$
```

How to adapt the regex expression to match numbers between 55 to 300?

Answer (score 3):

You change your regex to

```
^(?:5[5-9]|[6-9]\d|[1-2]\d{2})(?:\.\d+)?$|^300$
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/4rhz44/1/)

***On side note:-*** `\d{2,2}` is same as `\d{2}`

The regex you have will not match `300.00` you can extend it for this case too

```
^(?:5[5-9]|[6-9]\d|[1-2]\d{2})(?:\.\d+)?$|^300(?:\.0+)?$
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/4rhz44/4/)

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This does the job:

```
^(?:5[5-9]|[6-9]\d|[12]\d{2})(?:\.\d+)?$|^300$
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! :-)